# LESS: Generate SVG data-uri straight from text

Tags: css, svg, less

My app currently uses SVGs to support gradients for IE9 users. To save from having a lot of SVG files, we define them as data-uris in our CSS files. This does mean that we need to use a generator app to remake our gradients each time we have a slight change of color or direction.

I noticed this function in LESS, which is half of what might make this easier:
http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-data-uri

The other half would be if there were some way to run this function on pure text, as though it were the contents of a file. ie;

```
data-uri-from-text('image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8', '<svg> ... </svg')
```

Is there a way to do this in LESS?

Comment: [svg-gradient](http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-svg-gradient)?

Comment: @seven-phases-max Thanks! You should probably post that as an answer, as simple as it is. It's a little strange they don't use base64 encoding, but maybe there's a reason for it.